# C++ - MPEG TS - Parsing header - PID is messed up - Big endian 32 bits mask

Tags: c++, parsing, video-streaming, binary-data, mpeg2-ts

I think I'm having a tunnel vision here so I need your help.

I am trying to parse a [MPEG Transport-stream file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) and I'm stuck on the Header, on the wiki you will see that some 32bits BE MASK are provided in order to extract the data from the 4 bytes header. My code is taking into account endianess (I think) and reverses the bytes if it detects that you're running on a little endian. Then I cast the char* to an int and apply the mask, all the values look fine but the PID is messed up and I don't get why...

> header definition

```
namespace ts {

#define SYNC_BYTE_MASK 0xff000000
#define TEI_MASK 0x800000
#define PAYLOAD_START_MASK 0x400000
#define PRIORITY_MASK 0x200000
#define PID_MASK 0x1fff00
#define SCRAMBLING_CTL_MASK 0xc0
#define ADAPTATION_FIELD_MASK 0x20
#define HAS_PAYLOAD_MASK 0x10
#define COUNTER_MASK 0xf

#define HEADER_BYTES 4
#define HEADER_BITS 8 * HEADER_BYTES

class Header {

public:
    std::bitset<HEADER_BITS> *full;

    unsigned char _syncByte;
    bool _tei;
    bool _payloadStart;
    bool _priority;
    int16_t _pid;
    std::bitset<2> *_scramblingCtl;
    bool _adaptationField;
    bool _hasPayload;
    int _counter;

    Header(const char *, size_t);
    ~Header();

    const std::string toString();
    bool isValid();

};
```

}

> Header values assignment

```
ts::Header::Header(const char *header, size_t n) {
    uint32_t bytes = reverseLE(header, n);

    // just for display
    char t[4];
    memcpy(t, header, 4);
    std::cout << "Original: " << std::bitset<32>(*((uint32_t *)t)) << std::endl;
    this->full = new std::bitset<HEADER_BITS>(bytes);

    uint32_t tmp = bytes & SYNC_BYTE_MASK;
    this->_syncByte = ((char *)&tmp)[n - 1];

    this->_tei = bytes & TEI_MASK;
    this->_payloadStart = bytes & PAYLOAD_START_MASK;
    this->_priority = bytes & PRIORITY_MASK;
    this->_pid = bytes & PID_MASK; // THIS ONE IS MESSED UP !!
    this->_scramblingCtl = new std::bitset<2>(bytes & SCRAMBLING_CTL_MASK);
    this->_adaptationField = bytes & ADAPTATION_FIELD_MASK;
    this->_hasPayload = bytes & HAS_PAYLOAD_MASK;
    this->_counter = bytes & COUNTER_MASK;
}
```

> Functions to reverse

```
   #include "utils.h"

int is_big_endian(void)
{
    union {
        uint32_t i;
        char c[4];
    } e = { 0x01000000 };

    return e.c[0];
}

void swap(char *s, int a, int b) {
    char tmp;

    tmp = s[a];
    s[a] = s[b];
    s[b] = tmp;
}

// Converts string to int taking endianess into account
uint32_t reverseLE(const char *bits, size_t n) {
    uint32_t ret = 0;
    char *cp = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    memcpy(cp, bits, n);
    if ( ! is_big_endian() ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            swap(cp, i, n - 1 - i);
    }

    ret = *((uint32_t *)cp);
    free(cp);
    return ret;
}
```

Here's an example of an header that should have a PID of 33

```
Original: 00010010001000010000000001000111
Binary: 01000111000000000010000100010010
Sync byte: G
TEI: 0
Payload start: 0
Priority: 0
PID: 8448 0010000100000000
Scrambling Ctl: 00
Adaptation field: 0
Has Payload: 1
Counter: 2
```

Somehow it gets reversed again, and I don't get why...

Comment: You don't need to reverse bytes, as you are not reading an integer, but you are reading 4 bytes. They will always be in the right order. But outputting them using a bitset might be a problem.

Comment: I reverse because I need to apply the MASK (BE) on an int, and my machine is LE, so if I don't reverse before casting it's messed up, right? When I leave it as is, the bools are not set properly and neither is the PID :(

Comment: I see, you do use integers. But if you AND with `0x1fff00`, you should shift the result 8 bits (the zeros at the end). So your example has PID 33.

Comment: Ah ! good one, I have to account for the 4th byte... Post an answer if you care for the rep points :) . Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that the 13bits of the PID are located at `str[1]` and `str[2]` which means that after casting `*((int *)str)` and applying the mask there is still 8 trailing 0 bits from the last byte `str[3]`.

Solution:

```
this->_pid = bytes & PID_MASK; 
this->_pid >>= 8;
```

Thanks to @Wimmel.